# Create video from images and audio with varying image durations using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal, video-streaming

What I want to do:

I've x amount of images png/jpg, and I want to show them for varying amount of duration, some longer, and some shorter amount of time.

- a1.jpg 1st photo stays for 3 seconds
- a2.png stays for 10 seconds
- a3.jpg stays till end of audio

Video should be as long as audio.mp3

this is my code so far after reading documentation, not sure what's wrong, I get corrupt video with no sound and only shows last image.

Also would like to center images if possible.

```
ffmpeg -y \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a1.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a2.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 4 -i a3.jpg \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a4.png \
  -loop 1 -t 1 -i a5.png \
  -i audio.mp3 \
  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy video.mp4
```

Comment: Use method here: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer

Comment: I've read that like 8 times, however, approaches discussed either dont tell how to define duration or require me to use a text file

Comment: Yes, the text file is the method I suggested. The command can get unwieldy with other methods, especially for many images, but if you really want it that way, I'll add an answer.